# Let $\;U=\left\{p\in P_4(\mathbb{R}) : p''(6)=0\right\}.\;$ Find a basis of $U$.

Tags: linear-algebra

My approach here was to use the fact that $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^5$. So I wrote each polynomial in the list $1,\;x,\;(x-6)^3,\;(x-6)^4$ as a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^5$ relative to the standard basis of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ and then used Gaussian elimination on the corresponding matrix to ascertain linear independence.

Because the length of any linearly independent list in $U$ $\le$ the length of any spanning list in $U$, we have $\;\dim(U)\ge4$. And because $U$ is a subspace of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\;\dim(U)\le5$. Thus $4\le\dim(U)\le5$. Clearly $\;\dim(U)\neq5$. This is because $U$ is a subspace of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$, which means that if $\;\dim(U)=5=\dim(P_4(\mathbb{R}))$, then $U=P_4(\mathbb{R})$. However, $U$$\neq$$P_4(\mathbb{R})$ and hence $\;\dim(U)=4$. Thus the list of polynomials $1,\;x,\;(x-6)^3,\;(x-6)^4$ is a basis of $U$.

I've seen people use different methods here and so I'd like to know whether this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Using Taylor formula,

$\frac{(x-6)^0}{0!}, \frac{(x-6)^1}{1!}, \frac{(x-6)^3}{3!}, \frac{(x-6)^4}{4!}$ is a basis you’re looking for.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't the linearly independent list $1$,$x$,$(x-6)^3$,$(x-6)^4$ a basis of U? My understanding is that every linearly independent list in a vector space with length equal to the dimension of the vector space is a basis of the vector space.

Comment: @Karam You're right. And there is no contradiction between what you wrote and my answer. I'm just highlighting the fact that considering the condition $p^{\prime\prime}(6)=0$, using the polynomials derived from the Taylor formula is very natural.